# How to find a refernce for BigO complexity

Tags: citations, reference-request

I have a list of labels

```
A
B
C
...
...
Y
Z
```

I want to find the relation between every 2 letters

```
A-B
A-C
A-D
...
...
A-Z
B-C
B-D
B-E
...
...
B-Z
C-D
C-E
C-F
...
...
C-Z
...
...
Y-Z
```

I did the calculation and found that the BigO Complexity is $N^2/2$

Is there any academic reference I can cite for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May I suggest that you do not (yet) understand the meaning of big Oh completely? The number of all pairs taken from a list of n elements as you list them is $2\binom{n}{2} = n(n-1)$. Big Oh is a class of functions and the standard way of using it to characterize it by a monomial or other simple function in this class. In your case, the standard is to give the complexity class as $n^2$. Since the big Oh notation is introduced in classes on Data Structures and / or Algorithms, calculations like this usually do not warrant a citation. However, if you need one, look for a standard textbook on algorithms.

Comment: I haven't downvoted personally, but I'm speculating that it's because the root question is about the actual content of a subject or research rather than academia from a job based perspective.